# unable to use network sharing

Tags: networking, 13.10, dell, samba

I acquired a new pc to mess around with (a dell optiplex 760) and after installing synergy because I only have one mouse (synergy is used to share a keyboard, mouse and clipboard over multiple computers) I tried to set a few maps as shared so I can use it's hard drive as a data storage. It asked to install samba which is understandable so I allowed it to install samba.

It failed to install but it asked me to restart anyway so I did.

After the restart I couldn't connect with the pc. I removed samba and re-installed it (it failed again). However my dell can now connect with the shared files of my laptop (after giving my password for these files) but my laptop can not connect with the shared files of my dell.

It does prompt me for a password though but I do not have any samba users setup since I can't start samba (it isn't even listed in the dash but it must have changed something since I can now access files on remote pc's).

I disabled ufw on both computers so the install is a vanilla 13.10 besides for synergy and my laptop can access remote files on other computers and can be accessed by other computers.

Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing ubuntu 13.04

Didn't figure out why